# Classify pixels using deep learning model outputs blank raster

Tags: arcgis-pro, image-classification, deep-learning

I have been attempting to classify 0.5 m resolution imagery for my research. Unfortunately, when I go to run the "classify pixels using deep learning tool", I get an output with no errors, but the raster is seemingly blank.

I have collected extensive training points on all of the various land cover/habitat types of interest, exported the training data for deep learning, and trained the deep learning model. The following are my parameters for the "train deep learning model tool"...

[image]

I have also run this with the Deeplab model (which is what I initially planned on using). The same thing has happened both times. I subsequently run the "classify pixels using deep learning model" tool, using the .dlpk file that I get as output from the previous tool. The following is the raster info from the image I want to classify (i.e. my input raster for this tool)...

[image]

It appears as though the output raster that is supposed to be my classified image has pixels that have values of either 0 or 255, and when displayed on my map, it seems completely blank.

Other questions I have seen about this say to make sure your image is 8 bit unsigned, which mine is. I must be missing something here. This has been a very "learn as I go" experience.

I'm working with ArcGIS Pro 3.0.3 and have downloaded the required deep learning libraries associated with the tools that I am using.

Comment: I've had a play with the deep learning tools last year and in no way an expert in it so can't offer up why its failing but I did stumble across this [page](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-python-api/tree/master/guide/14-deep-learning) with worked examples, I found it useful as I stumbled around in this new world of jargon.